# Have a correct datetime with correct timezone

Tags: python, datetime, rss, feedparser

I am using `feedparser` in order to get RSS data.
Here is my code :

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import time
>>> import feedparser

>>> d=feedparser.parse("http://.../rss.xml")

>>> datetimee_rss = d.entries[0].published_parsed

>>> datetimee_rss
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=8, tm_hour=16, tm_min=57, tm_sec=39, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=128, tm_isdst=0)

>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(datetimee_rss))
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 8, 17, 57, 39)
```

In my timezone (FR), the actual date is  `May, 8th, 2015 18:57`.

In the RSS XML, the value is `<pubDate>Fri, 08 May 2015 18:57:39 +0200</pubDate>`

When I parse it into datetime, I got `2015, 5, 8, 17, 57, 39`.

How to have `2015, 5, 8, 18, 57, 39` without dirty hack, but simply by configuring the correct timezone ?

EDIT:

By doing :

```
>>> from pytz import timezone

>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(datetimee_rss),tz=timezone('Euro
pe/Paris'))
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 8, 17, 57, 39, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Paris' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
```

I got something nicer, however, it doesn't seem to work in the rest of the script, I got plenty of `TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes` error.

Comment: I don't know how feed parser handles those dates, but the resulting datetimes and time tuples aren't actually tz aware at all.

Comment: Aside from your Python problem, you should note that timestamps in RSS feeds are generally very messy and you should probably not "trust" them by default. Several services cheat by using their "discovery" date for news items.

Comment: @JulienGenestoux I've thought of that. I'll try it if I got too much complication in live environement :-) Thx !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`feedparser` does provide the original datetime string (just remove the `_parsed` suffix from the attribute name), so if you know the format of the string, you can parse it into a tz-aware datetime object yourself.

For example, with your code, you can get the tz-aware object as such:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(d.entries[0].published, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
```

for more reference on `strptime()`, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

EDIT: Since Python 2.x doesn't support `%z` directive, use `python-dateutil` instead

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

then

```
from dateutil import parser
datetime_rss = parser.parse(d.entries[0].published)
```

documentation at https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: I got the following error :`ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'`

Comment: If you are using Python 2.x, it doesn't support `%z`. Please check the updated answer above.

Comment: It's working in console, but the given datetime format generate exception when manipulating with other datetime such as "datatime.now()" : `TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes` (same as in my edited question). Is it possible to convert "offset-aware" to "offset-naive" ?

Comment: @Blusky you can't compare a tz-aware datetime object with a naive one, since the later don't have any timezone information. Do you have any idea what the timezone of your naive datetime object is?

Comment: local tz is 'Europe/Paris', the datetime is provided by datetime.datetime.now(). Isn't it strange that now doesn't have tz ?

Comment: Ok, that did it, I used `datetime_rss = parser.parse(d.entries[0].published).replace(tzinfo=None)`. Thank you very much !!!

Comment: @Blusky your solution is perfect if you can be confident that the timezone of the RSS feed is the same as your local timezone. If that's not the case (for example, you might be parsing an American feed whose timestamps are in EDT i.e. -0400), then you should account for the different timezones by converting everything to UTC.

Answer (score 1):

`feedparser` returns time in UTC timezone. It is incorrect to apply `time.mktime()` to it (unless your local timezone is UTC that it isn't). You should use `calendar.timegm()` instead:

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime

utc_tuple = d.entries[0].published_parsed
posix_timestamp = calendar.timegm(utc_tuple)
local_time_as_naive_datetime_object = datetime.frometimestamp(posix_timestamp) # assume non-"right" timezone
```

[RSS feeds may use many different dates formats](http://pythonhosted.org//feedparser/date-parsing.html); I would leave the date parsing to `feedparser` module.

If you want to get the local time as an aware datetime object:

```
from tzlocal import get_localzone # $ pip install tzlocal

local_timezone = get_localzone()
local_time = datetime.frometimestamp(posix_timestamp, local_timezone) # assume non-"right" timezone
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['TZ'] = 'Europe/Paris'
>>> time.tzset()
>>> time.tzname
('CET', 'CEST')
```

Comment: I got the following error :`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tzset'`. Apparently, tzset is only available for Linux. I am running on Windows, and would like the script to be multiplatform.
Any other idea ?